# Year wise archive of blog using views

Tags: views

Is it possible to generate a year-wise archive of blogs using views?I need years listed like 2001,2002,...2012 and clicking on the year should display list of blogs for that particular year.
I added a contextual Filter Content: Created year also , but it this query only

```
SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND))) AS created_year, COUNT(node.nid) AS num_records
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('blog')) ))
GROUP BY created_year, nid
ORDER BY created_year ASC
```

.So this results in duplicate value for years

Comment: Try to remove “Distinct” flag in “Query options”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check “Archive” view from standard Views install for start.
In your case you need to use contextual filter “Content: Created year” instead of “Content: Created year + month”.

[image]

Comment: I did like that, but it displays query like this only  <pre><code>SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM((DATE_ADD('19700101', INTERVAL node.created SECOND) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND))) AS created_year, COUNT(node.nid) AS num_records
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('blog')) ))
GROUP BY created_year, nid
ORDER BY created_year ASC</pre></code> and so it results in duplicate values

Comment: @user7282, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting. You can update your question to add more info about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to help you out.I am not sure whether it will work for you or not.
(Drupal 7) Go to your views, then go to advanced and go to query settings and check "distinct".